# Top 'n' results for each keyword

Tags: mysql

I have a query to get the top 'n' users who commented on a specific keyword,

```
SELECT `user` , COUNT( * ) AS magnitude
FROM `results`
WHERE `keyword` = "economy"
GROUP BY `user`
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 5
```

I have approx 6000 keywords, and would like to run this query to get me the top 'n' users for each and every keyword we have data for.  Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't given the schema for `results`, I'll assume it's this or very similar (maybe extra columns):

```
create table results (
  id int primary key,
  user int,
    foreign key (user) references <some_other_table>(id),
  keyword varchar(<30>)
);
```

**Step 1:** aggregate by `keyword/user` as in your example query, but for all keywords:

```
create view user_keyword as (
  select
    keyword,
    user,
    count(*) as magnitude
  from results
  group by keyword, user
);
```

**Step 2:** rank each user within each keyword group (note the use of the subquery to rank the rows):

```
create view keyword_user_ranked as (
  select 
    keyword,
    user,
    magnitude,
    (select count(*) 
     from user_keyword 
     where l.keyword = keyword and magnitude >= l.magnitude
    ) as rank
  from
    user_keyword l
);
```

**Step 3:** select only the rows where the rank is less than some number:

```
select * 
from keyword_user_ranked 
where rank <= 3;
```

---

Example:

Base data used:

```
mysql> select * from results;
+----+------+---------+
| id | user | keyword |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 |    1 | mysql   |
|  2 |    1 | mysql   |
|  3 |    2 | mysql   |
|  4 |    1 | query   |
|  5 |    2 | query   |
|  6 |    2 | query   |
|  7 |    2 | query   |
|  8 |    1 | table   |
|  9 |    2 | table   |
| 10 |    1 | table   |
| 11 |    3 | table   |
| 12 |    3 | mysql   |
| 13 |    3 | query   |
| 14 |    2 | mysql   |
| 15 |    1 | mysql   |
| 16 |    1 | mysql   |
| 17 |    3 | query   |
| 18 |    4 | mysql   |
| 19 |    4 | mysql   |
| 20 |    5 | mysql   |
+----+------+---------+
```

Grouped by keyword and user:

```
mysql> select * from user_keyword order by keyword, magnitude desc;
+---------+------+-----------+
| keyword | user | magnitude |
+---------+------+-----------+
| mysql   |    1 |         4 |
| mysql   |    2 |         2 |
| mysql   |    4 |         2 |
| mysql   |    3 |         1 |
| mysql   |    5 |         1 |
| query   |    2 |         3 |
| query   |    3 |         2 |
| query   |    1 |         1 |
| table   |    1 |         2 |
| table   |    2 |         1 |
| table   |    3 |         1 |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

Users ranked within keywords:

```
mysql> select * from keyword_user_ranked order by keyword, rank asc;
+---------+------+-----------+------+
| keyword | user | magnitude | rank |
+---------+------+-----------+------+
| mysql   |    1 |         4 |    1 |
| mysql   |    2 |         2 |    3 |
| mysql   |    4 |         2 |    3 |
| mysql   |    3 |         1 |    5 |
| mysql   |    5 |         1 |    5 |
| query   |    2 |         3 |    1 |
| query   |    3 |         2 |    2 |
| query   |    1 |         1 |    3 |
| table   |    1 |         2 |    1 |
| table   |    3 |         1 |    3 |
| table   |    2 |         1 |    3 |
+---------+------+-----------+------+
```

Only top 2 from each keyword:

```
mysql> select * from keyword_user_ranked where rank <= 2 order by keyword, rank asc;
+---------+------+-----------+------+
| keyword | user | magnitude | rank |
+---------+------+-----------+------+
| mysql   |    1 |         4 |    1 |
| query   |    2 |         3 |    1 |
| query   |    3 |         2 |    2 |
| table   |    1 |         2 |    1 |
+---------+------+-----------+------+
```

---

Note that when there are ties -- see users 2 and 4 for keyword "mysql" in the examples -- all parties in the tie get the "last" rank, i.e. if the 2nd and 3rd are tied, both are assigned rank 3.

---

Performance: adding an index to the keyword and user columns will help.  I have a table being queried in a similar way with 4000 and 1300 distinct values for the two columns (in a 600000-row table).  You can add the index like this:

```
alter table results add index keyword_user (keyword, user);
```

In my case, query time dropped from about 6 seconds to about 2 seconds.

Comment: Matt - Nice simple approach, I think however in my example with the size of data involved, the resource use will be too high.  Many thanks for your suggestion though, I have another process I am creating that will work nicely from this approach though.

Comment: @WAUS -- if you're able to track it and willing to share, I'd be interested in seeing the performance difference between the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like this (from [Within-group quotas (Top N per group)):](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104)

```
SELECT tmp.ID, tmp.entrydate 
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    ID, entrydate, 
    IF( @prev <> ID, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, 
    @prev := ID 
  FROM test t 
  JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r 
  ORDER BY t.ID 
) AS tmp 
WHERE tmp.rank <= 2 
ORDER BY ID, entrydate; 
+------+------------+ 
| ID   | entrydate  | 
+------+------------+ 
|    1 | 2007-05-01 | 
|    1 | 2007-05-02 | 
|    2 | 2007-06-03 | 
|    2 | 2007-06-04 | 
|    3 | 2007-07-01 | 
|    3 | 2007-07-02 | 
+------+------------+
```

Comment: Venk - no error per se on the query I posted, I just need this to run across all keywords in the table not just one one specified keyword.  Efficiency is important as this will return 'n' x 6000 results