# Get top-k of each group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I omit the steps before the last one. I get the table like: `year, month, postid, clicks`. How do I get top-k `postid` for each `year, month` group?

For example, I have data:

```
2012,1,a,5
2012,1,b,3
2012,1,c,8
2012,2,a,2
2012,2,c,5
2012,2,d,6
```

Assuming `k=2`, I want the results like:

```
2012,1,c,8
2012,1,a,5
2012,2,d,6
2012,2,c,5
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Top 'n' results for each keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692041/top-n-results-for-each-keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select postid, clicks,
    @num := if(@year = @year and @month = month, @num + 1, 1) row_number,
    @year := year year, @month := month month
from (
    select * from t
    order by year, month, clicks desc
) s, (select @num := 0, @year := '', @month := '') init
group by year, month, postid, clicks
having row_number <= 2
order by year, month, clicks desc
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fdbb/1)