# mysql - getting top K options per each group

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

During my experience with MySQL, I encountered in many opportunities a task to find the best (max/min) row per group.

For example in Table:

> **Grades**(Student_ID, Course_ID, Grade)

to find the **top course per each student** we can use the correlated-subquery:

```
SELECT Student_ID, Course_ID
FROM Grades g1
WHERE Grade in (SELECT MAX(Grade)
                FROM Grades g2
                WHERE g1.Student_ID = g2.Student_ID)
```

But - how can I do the same for **TOP K** courses?

[I found this answer from related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179649/get-top-k-of-each-group-in-mysql), but they it is using variables, which are not a part of classical SQL. Is there any other solution, or I must use variables in this case?

Comment: See http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranking technique using MySQL `@variables` is a way to work around the absence of the `RANK()` or `ROWNUM()` window functions from that database.

The recently released fork of [MySQL MariaDB 10.2, has `RANK()` and related functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/rank/). MySQL from Oracle, not yet.

You're not the only one who wishes MySQL didn't need  `@variables` to do this kind of query.